# Pushing notifications at set interval based on the state of the shopping cart? /Ionic

Tags: android, ios, cordova, notifications, ionic-framework

We're building an ecommerce hybrid app (Ionic + Phonegap + Cordova) where users can put items in the shopping cart before buying them (similar to Amazon and other ecommerce services).

To encourage users to finish the purchase, we wanted to "scan" the shopping cart once per day and check if the user has some items in the shopping cart that have been there for more than 24 hrs.

They would then be notified daily at 3pm via push notifications if the algorithm finds any items that have been in the cart for more than 24 hrs. If there are no such items, no notifications will be sent. If there are multiple items, only 1 notification will be sent saying "I see you have 2 items in the cart you haven't bought yet. What are you waiting for?".

I am a non-technical member of the team and I have been told by the engineers that creating such notifications is not possible.

What I've been told, verbatim:

> Unfortunately, due to the Apple and Android settings, code can't be
>   executed after the notification is shown. What that means is that we
>   can't check in the background for any outstanding items from the past
>   few days. The best thing we can do, is to plan a notification for the
>   next day if user has opened the application and there are items in the
>   cart. However, there is no way how to plan it for next X days.

The proposed solution is this:

> When the user adds a new item, all scheduled notifications [as
>   mentioned above] will be deleted and new notifications will be
>   calculated (it gets difficult in this part because of grouping items
>   as we don't want to spam users with the notifications)

So my question is straightforward - is this a sensible solution and is there really nothing more efficient? Thank you.

Comment: The shpping cart state is saved only in client side?

Comment: When there is no connection, yes. As soon as the app detects the network connection, the information is synced to the server -> the same way as taking notes with any of the popular note-taking apps. However, we do not know for sure that the user would be online within 1 day, though most of them will be.

Comment: I might be missing something, but if most of the time the data is synced to the server, what is the problem? also taking into account that the app you're describing is not an app that suppose to work without internet connection.

Comment: The app will work w/o the connection only with the cached data. I do not have sufficient experience with Ionic so I am not in position to answer your question but I assume that this is the case: 1) I put 2 items in the cart, 2) I close the app and not connect to the internet for > 1 day. That's why I asked if the proposed solution by engineers makes sense or if there is something better, what were you suggesting?

Comment: Maybe my assumption is wrong, but if the user closed the app and is not connected to the internet for more than 1 day, why would you want to do something? While he's not connected he won't get push notification anyway and if he connects, then you can sync the data and decide what to do.

Comment: Yes, that's the thing. Say we would want to reduce the cart abandonment rate or if they leave the app for even longer (30 days), we could try to reactivate them. The underlying assumption is, however, that they do not have the internet connection. So we would send a notification saying "Hey! We've noticed you haven't used the app for 30 days. There are still items in your cart.." (for example)

Comment: If they don't have an internet connection they won't get the push notification even if you send it. The push will be sent only when they are back online.

Comment: Oh, ok. Is that why you asked if the cart state is saved only in client side? If it would be, that means there is no way to send the notification?

Comment: No, the reason I asked is because of this line:
"Unfortunately, due to the Apple and Android settings, code can't be executed after the notification is shown" - because if the data is on the server side, then there is no reason to execute code on the client side (which on a side note is something you can do using a broadcast receiver on Android and Background Execution on iOS)

Comment: Ok, thank for the insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a two types of notifications:

**Local Notification:**

The notification is created in your app. One strategy can be:

- Have an event handler for pausing and and another one for resuming of
  the app.
- If the app is going to pause, you calculate the notification text,
  the date and time and maybe a badge. ( "You have two item in …",
  shown in 24 hours.)
- If the app resumes, you clear the notification(s).

You can create multiple notifications, but there is no useable way to make a recalculation, if the app is not in the foreground. For a short time you can have a background process, but it is not allowed to have this one for a longer time. (A special situation are GPS tracking and timer apps.)

**Push Notifications:**

This kind of notifications are send from notification providers like Google, Apple, …. Therefore you have to save the shopping data on your server and send a notification job to this providers, which delivers it then to the clients.

Push notifications are a bigger job to develop then the local once. The reason is, that you have to manage the shopping data, the devices and the communication with the notification servers. And you will have a lot of trash and fake data.

I would start with the local notification.,